# Change HTTPS to HTTP for three pages on our site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am looking to exclude 3 pages from my https. So to force them to use http:// instead of my rule to set to https:// - I've tried many ways but believe my https rule is overriding them. If anyone can help me write an exclusion for those pages within my rules? Is this even possible?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([^\.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this -

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(page1|page2|page3) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

Not sure which all three pages you want to exclude from https hence have used page1,page2 and page3 for example.

Comment: This appears to make none of my pages https:// if I use this rule. I did find an example like yours above and had tried that but to no success - unsure how to improve it, if at all possible